# How to use filters in GuzzleHttp in Laravel?

Tags: wordpress, laravel, guzzle

I am currently using WordPress with Laravel. I write posts in WordPress and display the posts in  my Laravel application using WordPress REST API and GuzzleHttp.
Is there any way I can use different filters like where(), sortBy() etc. for filtering the data received from WordPress REST API using GuzzleHttp?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can serialize the json response to a [Laravel Collection](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/collections) and use [functions like that](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/collections#available-methods) from there.

1. Retrieve the response body, which we assume contains json.

   ```
   $response = $response->getBody();
   ```
2. Turn the json into an array. Note the [seconds parameter](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) is set to `true` to always output an array.

   ```
   $responseArray - json_decode($response, true);
   ```
3. Turn the array into a Laravel collection in order to use its cool functions.

   ```
   $collection = collect($responseArray);
   ```

So in short:

```
$collection = collect( json_decode( $response->getBody(), true ) );
$sortedByPrice = $collection->sortBy('price');
```